# Stack Overflow in multi threaded application

Tags: c#, stack-overflow, stack, overflow

Hopefully someone can help me out a little bit. I have a c# application running under .NET 2.0. It's a strange app. It is listening on the network for any UDP packets. When it receives a UDP packet with the first 8 bytes spelling out 'Catalina', it parses the packet and then sends the information to an appropriate socket connection (async socket connections). If there are 8 client terminals, then there would be 8 additional sockets that the decrypted UDP packet info would be directed to. Actually just the one that the packet is intended for. My application can run for one hour or maybe three hours but eventually, I get a stack overflow, usually in msCorLib.dll. If I tell visual studio to stop on stack overflows, it's at different places. I really dont see (or cant find) any recursive loops, and like I said the app will run for x amout of time before it craps out. Basically I am looking for a utility that I can purchase that will help me find out why this is happening. Ive never really had to dig this deep into a problem that was so hard to find or moving so much. Does anyone know of any utilitites that might help me out?

Thank you so much in advance for any advice,
Mike

Comment: Obligatory "stack overflow on stackoverflow.com!" comment goes here.

Comment: @BoltClock's a Unicorn +1 for the recursion

Comment: It sounds to me like an accidental loop starting each batch - can you post any code?

Comment: There is a chance that the packet decoding is simply stack hungry for certain content. Did you try to send the exact same packet that breaks it again to see what happens?